# SQl - find average amount per person

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

```
class
| id      | area       | students  |
|       1 |      area1 |     2     |
|       2 |      area1 |     28    |
|       3 |      area1 |     22    |
|       4 |      area2 |     4     |

deliveries
| id      | kg         | classid   |
|       1 |      120   |     1     |
|       2 |      80    |     1     |
|       3 |      20    |     1     |
|       4 |      200   |     2     |
|       5 |      150   |     3     |
|       6 |      14    |     2     |
```

I need to sum up the average of kg delivered per student in a each area.

For area1 that should amount to (120+80+20+200+150+14)/(2+28+22) = 11.23
But I can't figure out how to write that query. I guess I have to use some kind of subquery to first sum out students in area1 (52), before I sum kg delivered and divide on students?

Comment: Do a JOIN with GROUP BY. Use AVG().

Comment: it will not help here

Comment: do you just need only avg ?

Comment: Ok I've rolled back the edit. will post a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little tricky, because the students should be counted separately from the classes:

```
select c.area, sum(d.kg) / max(area_students) as avg_kg_per_student
from class c join
     deliveries d
     on d.classid = c.id join
     (select c2.area, sum(students) as area_students
      from class c2
      group by c2.area
     ) c2
     on c2.area = c.area
group by c.area;
```

Comment: what you think about my ans ?

Comment: That looks about right. Now I just have to try and understand whats happening :)

Comment: Upvoted. This seems to be the best answer... The reason it only returned one row was that only one area had deliveries in the original table. Heres one with two deliveries: http://rextester.com/edit/FYD1458

Comment: OK I did something stupid. Thought the easiest way to find an answer was to show the example with two tables. But I actually have three tables, and I can't get to solution to work with three table. I apologize! Is it possible to get a working solution with three tables?

Comment: @johnohod . . . You should ask new questions as a *new* question and not in a comment.  Be sure to include sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot use average because you need to determine the denominator yourself:

```
SELECT sum(kg)/ studSum AS avg 
FROM _class LEFT JOIN _deliveries ON _class.id=_deliveries.classid 
            left join (select area, sum(students) as studSum from _class group by area) subT 
            ON subT.area=_class.area
GROUP BY _class.area;
```

Comment: here some of student is more then actual

Comment: generates: `Unknown column 'studSum' in 'field list'`

Comment: @MichaelK check it now

Comment: seems really heavy!: `Process killed because it exceeded given resources.
Cpu time used 0,234375 sec, absolute running time 15 sec, memory used 26 Mb, nr of threads 12` http://rextester.com/CGUE44253

Comment: @MichaelK  Edited it now.

Comment: Nice, works better! But the strange thing is.. both your example and @Gordons give another average sum when more deliveries are added to another area. For instance change classid to `4` instead of `3` in table  deliveries, then the sum is `8,34` instead of `11.23` for area 1: http://rextester.com/SXNOF82695

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very readable approach: Get students per area and kg per area, then join the two.

```
select stu.area, stu.students, del.kg, del.kg / stu.students
from
(
  select area, sum(students) as students
  from class
  group by area
) stu
join
(
  select c.area, sum(d.kg) as kg
  from class c
  join deliveries d on d.classid = c.classid
  group by c.area
) del on del.area = stu.area;
```